# How to bulk insert array of records, each containing array of subrecords Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bulkinsert

Here are the classes in use:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes,  autosave: true
end
```

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
  has_many :ingredients, through: :parts

  belongs_to :author, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
end
```

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :parts
  belongs_to :ingredient, inverse_of: :parts
end
```

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
  has_many :recipes, through: :parts
end
```

As you notice, many-to-many relationship is modeled using :through, to avoid using deprecated `has_and_belongs_to_many` and to gain more flexibility.

I need to seed thousands of recipes, each belonging to one author and each contains one or more ingredients. Obviously, creating thousands of insert statements is far from the optimised solution. Each ingredient can belong to one or more recipes. I have 3 questions:

1. Is there any way to save all the things in a single statement?

I have tried using `activerecord-import` gem, but it does not support `:through` relationsip, as stated in this issue: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/issues/630. Also, insert_all is an option, but it requires iterating over array of hashes after inserting each record, which is pretty dirty solution. Also, there was no luck in trying to make `insert_all` works when using :through for many-to-many relationship.

2. Is there a way to bulk insert recipes with authors in the same statement? Similar to this

```
recipes.each do |r|
  r.author = Author.new(name: '<random name>')
end

Recipe.insert_all(recipes)
```

I need to save recipes and author for each recipe (obviously even before the receipt is saved).

This does not work with activerecord-import gem. It throws NotNullConstraintViolation (it complaints that author id cannot be null when bulk saving recipes).

I know this is kind of weird since to save receipt it has to have author id, but is there some magic in active record/postgres to do this?

3. Which are advantages of using `activerecord-import` instead of insert_all, except it returns array of models and insert_all returns array of hashes-attributes ?

To add to this, it's not an option to use plain SQL query for this

Comment: What is your input data? Is it one-time operation or you will use it many times? Show some code how did you try to accomplish your goal.

Comment: It's basically one time operation - I want to seed thousands of records from JSON file to DB

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` is moderately useless - but its not deprechiated.